# Electrodynamics confusion - Hertzian dipole

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, dipole, antennas

I am studying a course in Electrodynamics and we are just covering retarded potentials and the Hertzian dipole.

In my lecture notes, we have calculated the magnetic vector potential $A$ in the Lorenz gauge as $$A = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi r} [\ddot{p}]$$ where the square brackets indicated evaluated at the retarded time.

Now the confusion comes in once we start to compute the fields $B$ and $E$.

Calculation of $B$ is easy enough using $B = \nabla \times A$, but for $E$ we are using $$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \nabla \times B$$ but where has the $\mu_0 j$ gone from this equation (Ampere's law??)?? I don't know if it has anything to do with the fact we are neglected terms in $\frac{1}{r^2}$ and higher, but I am quite confused about where this equation has come from.

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: There should be only single dot above $p$ in that expression for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the $E$ field far away due to a radiating dipole. That is, your entire universe is a radiating dipole and you want to know what the $E$ field looks like some distance away *in the absence of anything else*, as if you added a current in the mix then that would be the $E$ field for a radiating dipole *and* due to a free current. Since our desired analysis is to study a dipole only, we simply impose that there are no free currents in our region of interest. That is, $\mathbf{J} =0$.

Comment: Don’t we have a current through the dipole though? Or is the j in Maxwell only referring to ‘free currents’? What even constitutes a ‘free current’

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But your $I_{enc}$ in the region you're looking for the $E$-field is zero. You can see it that way, that's fine but then you *could say that* "well we shouldn't get rid of it *yet* then. That's fine. However, another way of thinking about it is what you are writing down is maxwells equations **in a given region ** (i.e. a domain). And since you are solving maxwells equations in the region where $\mathbf{J} =0$ we may just go ahead and set it to zero.